# How to retrieve the FutureReleaseEntry release notes in squirrel windows?

Tags: c#, squirrel.windows

Hi i started using squirrel in my app and I can update my app smoothly from the web location(where i put my setup, versions)

I want to get the release notes for the future version. 
I can get get the future version's version number however, i couldnt get the release notes of it.

Here's my code

```
using (var mgr = new UpdateManager(@"http://mysamplewebsite.com/version/"))
{
               var updateInfo = await mgr.CheckForUpdate();

                if (updateInfo.ReleasesToApply.Any())
                {
                    string futureVersion = updateInfo.FutureReleaseEntry.Version.ToString();
                   //GOOD
                    MessageBox.Show(futureVersion);

                   var futureReleaseNotesLocalDirectory = updateInfo.FutureReleaseEntry.GetReleaseNotes(@"C:\Users\source\repos\UpdateAppTesting\Releases");
                    //GOOD I can even get the release notes in my local directory
                    MessageBox.Show(futureReleaseNotesLocalDirectory);


                 //giving me an error of URI FORMATs are not supported
                  var futureReleaseNotesWEBLocation = updateInfo.FutureReleaseEntry.GetReleaseNotes(@"http://mysamplewebsite.com/version/");
                    MessageBox.Show(futureReleaseNotesWEBLocation);
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("No updates detected.");
                }
}
```

While i can get the update's release notes through the directory , I cannot get the release notes through web url location.

The web url location is working because i can get the future version's version number. 
But when i am trying to get the release notes, its giving me an error of
**URI FORMATs are not supported**

Hope someone can help me, because release note is very important for the user know what is the new update/changes from the app. 
Thanks

Comment: The [code](https://github.com/Squirrel/Squirrel.Windows/blob/master/src/Squirrel/ReleaseEntry.cs#L77) expects them to be local. Can you download the release notes to the local temp folder and open them from there?

Comment: Oh thanks, yeah it expects them to be local.
But do you have an idea how can i download the release notes and put in my local dir @stuartd

Answer (score 0):

#### TL;DR

```
updateInfo.FutureReleaseEntry.GetReleaseNotes(updateInfo.PackageDirectory)
```

---

First you have to download the release with

```
mgr.DownloadReleases(updateInfo.ReleasesToApply)
```

Or

```
mgr.UpdateApp()
```

the nuget packages are stored in the folder `packages` at the App root's directory.

You can access that folder like this

```
updateInfo.PackageDirectory
```

And to get the release notes

```
updateInfo.FutureReleaseEntry.GetReleaseNotes(updateInfo.PackageDirectory)
```

But this means you have to download the entire release before you can access de **release notes**